# Adding Open CSV reader library to GWT- getting error message

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt, jar, opencsv

Im using [this](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#what-is-opencsv) library to parse CSV files in my GWT app. However, It compiles fine however, Im getting an error at runtime in the console.

In order to include it in my GWT project, I also copied the jar file into my WEB-INF->libfolder.

Then I added the path to my project at project-> rightclick->configurebuildpath...

But now Im seeing these errors on the console when I run the app:

```
    [ERROR] Line 23: No source code is available for type au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[ERROR] Line 71: No source code is available for type java.io.FileReader; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[ERROR] Line 74: No source code is available for type java.io.FileNotFoundException; did you forget to inherit a required module?
    [ERROR] Unable to load module entry point class cs310.client.Main (see associated exception for details)
    [ERROR] Failed to load module 'XXXX' from user agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5' at localhost:59443
```

Can anyone offer any suggestions on what exactly Ive done wrong and how do I get this to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT apps being browser apps do not have access to the local filesystem, that's why GWT [doesn't emulate](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation#Package_java_io) `java.io.FileReader` and related exceptions (most of `java.io.*`, for that matter). If the library insists on filesystem access it won't work with GWT.